# Importing a Named and Subscribed Calendar into an App and displaying all events

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, icalendar

So basically, I am having trouble with an app I am trying to make.

The goal is to import a specific subscribed calendar from iCal and put all the events into it in an array.

Ive managed to request access to calendars.
Ive managed to import all calendars and just display subscribed calendars using

```
NSArray *allCalendars = [self.eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
NSMutableArray *localCalendars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i<allCalendars.count; i++) {
    EKCalendar *currentCalendar = [allCalendars objectAtIndex:i];
    if (currentCalendar.type == EKCalendarTypeSubscription) {
        NSLog(@"%@", currentCalendar);
```

Now I would like to narrow that down to a specific calendar named say "Big Calendar".
I would then like all the events in that calendar displayed in an array.

Is that possible and a relatively efficient way of achieving the goal?

Any suggestions on how to code this?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use title property and check if title == @"Big Calendar" then import it.

```
for (int i=0; i<allCalendars.count; i++) {
    EKCalendar *currentCalendar = [allCalendars objectAtIndex:i];
    if (currentCalendar.type == EKCalendarTypeSubscription && currentCalendar.title == @"Big Calendar") {
        NSLog(@"%@", currentCalendar);
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: No luck, I think its because allowsModify = NO, on the calendar i want. is there a way around this?